# Tracing into MFC created with Visual Studio 2015 not working

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I can't seem to trace into the MFC library if I created the project in 2015. I've had 2015 for a while and have moved 2010 project up to 2015 and they don't have this problem. All the symbols are being loaded. And, I can cheat the issue by opening a disassembly window, tracing in, then closing the disassembly window. From there I can trace into MFC call after call fine. But as soon as I trace up to my own code, I can't trace back into MFC.

I've searched best I can but found nothing even close.

I just don't know if this is new since I applied SP3 some weeks ago. It has just shown up in recently created projects. I've tested with a Dialog and an SDI app. They both won't trace. It just steps over, no messages.

The 2010 and the 2015 created project look the same. Unicode, dynamically linked, v140 compiler. It is as if there is some little difference, but why it would cause tracing to act like this is elusive for me.

**Update:**
Just to test. I create a Dialog app in 2010 and versioned it up to 2015. I can trace into MFC fine if I do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the [Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) option from the *Debugging* → *General* dialog in the *Options*.

Comment: Thanks. But it just got weirder. With `just my code` on in the old projects, I can trace into MFC. I turned it off in the new project and the problem persists.

Comment: I just installed 2019. They had `Just My Code` turned on. So I found myself here, again. So you get the vote.

Answer (score 2):

Using the two projects I could alt-tab between the properties and look for differences. I got to `Linker -> Debugging` and found that Generate Debug Info was different.

From 2010 it was:

`Optimize for debugging (/DEBUG)`

And for a new 2015 project it was:

`Optimize for faster linking (/DEBUG:FASTLINK)`

Changing the 2015 generated linking from `/DEBUG:FASTLINK` to just `/DEBUG` and I could trace into MFC. I would add, this only seems to affect MFC. I could still trace into ATL and other libraries.